# Use JavaScript to replace a date inside of a string

Tags: javascript, date

I am struggling with javaScript replace and dates.

In short, I have a string that has a date inside of it. I need to replace that date with a newly formatted date, while maintaining the string.

```
var d1 = 'We met on 2014-02-20';
var d2 = 'I saw you again on Thursday, June 05, 2012';
var d3 = 'We had a great day on 2/15/2013';
var d4 = 'On March 07, 2015 we had to go to school';
var d5 = 'The vacation is between 1/1/15 and 1/2/15';
```

What I need is to get a standard date in all of these lines, but every solution just extracts the date and prints it. The best article I have found involves JQUERY UI [`var dt1 = $.datepicker.formatDate('D, d M yy', new Date(d1));`], which works great, but it strips the date out of the string and I am left with the date only.

What I am trying to achieve is something like this:

```
var d1 = 'We met on 2014-02-20';
var d2 = 'I saw you again on Thursday, June 05, 2012';
var d3 = 'We had a great day on 2/15/2013';
var d4 = 'On March 07, 2015 we had to go to school';
```

**TO**

```
print_date_str(d1);
```

We met on **Mon, 20 Feb 2014**

```
print_date_str(d2);
```

I saw you again on **Thu, 05 Jun 2012**

```
print_date_str(d3);
```

We had a great day on **Sun, 15 Feb 2013**

```
print_date_str(d4);
```

On **Fri, 07 Mar 2015** we had to go to school

```
print_date_str(d5);
```

'The vacation is between **Tue, 01 Jan 2015** and **Wed, 02 Jan 2015**'

Here is a JSFIDDLE showing Jquery UI date format: http://jsfiddle.net/k7qrw8o7/1/

Your guidance and help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you give a complete example? how do you use datepicker? what do you expect to happen with a string like 'The vacation is between 1/1/15 and 1/2/15' ?

Comment: Is it assumed that the variables are going to have text in them instead of just a date? If so, then it would be harder as you'll have to look through the text for a date format, and considering you have such a wide variety of date formats, this could be a headache. If we can assume strings are going to have a date only, this would be handled by Javascript's `Date()` object.

Comment: @Amit - I added in a example (d5) from your comment.

Comment: Just have the dates be a separate variable, convert them, and then concatenate them in the string. Otherwise you are going to need some complex regular expression that will not likely work for all cases to find and replace the dates.

Comment: @ThoughtSpaceDesigns - Jquery UI datepicker seams to have a handle on finding RFC dates inside of a string, but it just deletes the rest of the text. So it must be possible in some level of regex, digging JQUERY UI code seams futile (I tried).

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek - the dates are already in the text, like parsing a web page or chat text. No way to get them into a variable.

Comment: Why all the date formats? Is this user generated data? Or can you control the format of the date end to end?

Comment: @Nindaff - great question, parsing a existing web page, or a text message, or a chat text.

Comment: I added in a JS Fiddle of the closest example I can find to what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good site to reference for formatting JavaScript dates. [MS JS time](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff743760(v=vs.94).aspx)
`var date = new Date(Date.UTC(2014, 1, 20));` then you would do `var d1Date = date.toLocaleDateString("en-US")` then `var d1 = 'We met on '+ d1Date;`

Comment: That is just concatenating a string, I need to replace the date inside of the string.

Comment: You can replace the date inside of the string by concatenating the string with a variable and then manipulating the variable how ever you like. If you ever want to change the date in d1 just change to var d1Date

Comment: So how would you extract the date as a variable and then leave a place holder so the date does back into the correct place? 'This date 2015/04/05 is in the middle', so you need to change that to 'This date'+ var_date +'is in the middle'

Comment: yes that is correct, then you would manipulate var_date to change the date in that sentence

Comment: But each sentence is different.  So how would you know where to concat.  Really it needs to be var.replace(date, val); Maybe I am not understanding you correctly, can you update your answer with an example based on the variables that I have posted?